# How to create Forgot password user endpoint API in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

How can we use custom code to generate a password for the forgot password user endpoint API?

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin: **bdvs password reset**

You can simply reset password and set new password. I put example some code:

**Reset Password**:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-json/bdpwr/v1/reset-password',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    email: 'example@example.com',
  },
  success: function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
  },
  error: function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
  },
});
```

**Set New Password:**

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/wp-json/bdpwr/v1/set-password',
  method: 'POST',
  data: {
    email: 'example@example.com',
    code: '1234',
    password: 'Pa$$word1',
  },
  success: function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
  },
  error: function( response ) {
    console.log( response );
  },
});
```

Comment: We need purely custom code not using third part plugin. Thanks!!!

Comment: You can check the plugin's codes, Maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress generates passwords by function `wp_generate_password()` - [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_generate_password/)

At the end of the function there is hook `random_password`, so if you wnat to use your custom code to generate a password instead of native WP function, you need to add filter and in function you can write your custom code for generating password. This function will be called always at the end of `wp_generate_password()`.

```
function custom_random_password( $password ) {
  // here you make your password generation
  $password = 'your-password';
  return $password; 
}
add_filter( 'random_password', 'custom_random_password' );
```

Comment: Not a using filter we need to setup user endpoint using register_rest_route.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.